# Automatically set expiry date in Postgres while inserting a record

Tags: postgresql

I have a course table where joining date is now() but need to set an monthly_expiry_day -->which is now + 1 month.
How to set this column automatically when we insert a course ?

Comment: Is it only possible by using trigger function like when insert event trigger to update the record ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "automatically"? Can you show us the query that does the insertion? Can you change that query?

Comment: I mean like whenever we insert a record in a table inside that table i have a column named course_expiry. which i need to set automatically as joining date + 30 days interval.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that is to change the insertion statement.

Comment: Acutally this is what i meant, but somehow it is not updating the expiry column(trigger not working)                                                                                          
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tvm_noopura.insert_course_expiry()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
        UPDATE tvm_noopura.student_course set course_expiry = course_expiry + interval '';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON tvm_noopura.student_course
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tvm_noopura.insert_course_expiry();

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, with formatting.

Comment: I guess you'll want to set `NEW.course_expiry = now() + interval;`. Not update the whole table.

Comment: Sorry Bergi (I'm new on posting questions in stackoverflow !).

Comment: Yes, this can only be done in a trigger

Answer (score 1):

Also add the trigger to call the function

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER set_course_expiry_Trigger 
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON student_course 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_course_expiry();
```

Comment: Don't add additional code for your answer as _another_ answer. [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58393506/edit) your original answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign this value in a BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_course_expiry()
 RETURNS trigger AS
$$ 
BEGIN 
  new.course_expiry = current_date + interval '1 year';
  return new;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then create a trigger:

```
create trigger set_expiry_trigger 
  before insert on student_course
  for each row
  execute procedure insert_course_expiry();
```